# The usage of 'to'

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

My problem is that I don't know whether I should use 'to' or not when I say the sentences I wrote below. Can anyone tell me which one is right and why, 'have you gotten New York safely?' or 'have you gotten to New York safely?'? I don't know what to say when it comes to those. I get confused. I often hear people say 'did you get home?' and 'did you go home?' and they don't use 'to'. But they also say '...go(get) to your office...' or '...go to school'. I want to know the reason.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. You need English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sound of *got-to* run together may have left you thinking of *gotten*.

Only the animal catching its prey has gotten its meal.

Using simpler words the right meaning would come through more easily.

'Did or will you get to New York safely?'

'Have you got to New York safely?'

'Had I got to New York safely I would have called'

These are all about a destination of a city or place where *to* would be correct.
From *to* the state of New York *to* the city, *to* my street or *to* my house these all use *to*. Going to my home would be correct as well but it would be fine to say you went home. Or did you go home or get home. The nature of this exception baffles me.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Then, would you please tell me if it is 'I'm on my way back 'to' where I belong.' or 'I'm on my way back where I belong?

Comment: Either of those would work and not make a bad sound as English but I'd pick the second. Leaving 'to' in or not would then be important for keeping the number of syllables right for the song lyrics.

Comment: “Going to my home” is very commonly heard from non-native speakers (speakers of Romance languages especially), but I’ve never heard a native speaker say it. _Home_ is a sort of weird pseudo-preposition on its own and does not normally take any preposition to indicate movement-towards. Same with words like _(t)here_ and _back_. “*I went to home/there/back” is quite ungrammatical. (Note that _house_ is different from _home_: “Went to my house” is fine, but “*went to (my) home” is not.)